# My PowerShell console hangs. How do I fix it?

Tags: powershell, freeze

My PowerShell console hangs.

[image: Screenshot of PowerShell console]

I restarted the "Windows Update" service and the "Windows Remote Management" service but it's still not loading.
I know a server restart would fix the issue but I would like to have a solution which wouldn't require that option.

Comment: As a shot to nothing, try starting a regular command prompt and running ```powershell.exe -NoProfile``` and see if that loads. It might be a profile script hanging rather than Windows PowerShell itself.

Comment: See following : https://windowsreport.com/windows-powershell-stopped-working/?force_isolation=true